# Excel SumIFS between dates and text criteria

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

## Data

```
        A        B        C             D            E       F      AG     
1     Item     Total   2017-11-01   2017-11-02   2017-11-03  ..   2017-12-01
2    ItemA       6        1             2            2       ..     1
3    ItemB       8        2             2            2       ..     2
```

The above data page will keep pasting new data every month.
I want to set a sum formula on below Summary page to sum all the data from Data Sheet.

## Summary Page

```
        A        B           C          D     
1     Item    Nov-2017    Dec-2017   Jan-2018
2    ItemA       5           1          0
3    ItemB       6           2          0
```

Any formula works for this summary page to check the data  month with year and the ITEM textName.

Comment: It is easy to do using power query and a pivot table. Have you ever try it?

Comment: nope... im bad in excel knownledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the add-in Power Query for Excel 2010 it is free a easy to activate.

1. Select any cell in your main table.
2. Go to **Power Pivot** tab and select **From Range/Table** click **ok**

It will open the **Power Query Editor**

3. Select the first column.
4. Right click or go to **Transform** tab and select **Unpivot other columns**
5. You can extract Year and Month there if you want
6. Go to **Home** tab and select **Close & Load**

Now you can create a pivot table and get the result that you want to.

I would recommend you connect directly your data source to **Power Query** because it seems you will run out of columns in your main data if that is posible.